# Performing multiple ansible.builtin.blockinfile tasks on the same file?

Tags: ansible

I have found that if you have multiple ansible.builtin.blockinfile tasks for a single file, the last blockinfile task will overwrite the contents of a single `# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK {mark} # END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK`. I was expecting it to work like lineinfile, which can perform multiple replacements in multiple areas of a file.

Is there a way around this?

Initial file:

```
ini.foo=bar

ini.bar=foo
```

Task file:

```
- blockinfile:
   path: /my/file
   block: |
    block1
    block1
    block1
   insertbefore: '^ini.foo=bar'

- blockinfile:
   path: /my/file
   block: |
    block2
    block2
    block2
   insertbefore: '^ini.bar=foo'
```

Expected result:

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
    block1
    block1
    block1
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
ini.foo=bar

# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
    block2
    block2
    block2
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
ini.bar=foo
```

Actual result:

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
    block2
    block2
    block2
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
ini.foo=bar

ini.bar=foo
```

Note how the second task replaces the content of the first replacement, and doesn't respect its own `insertbefore` parameter.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You need to change the [`marker`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-marker) so that it is unique for each block. Please read the doc carefully and don't forget to add the `{mark}` substring inside your marker.

Comment: lineinfile marker is.... a line. A block needs some other way to be identified. Note that managing numerous blocks in a file is usually a pretty good sign your should consider switching to a template.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `marker` to separate block messages.
Your code should be something like this:

```yaml
- blockinfile:
   path: /my/file
   marker: "{mark} block1"
   block: |
    block1
    block1
    block1
   insertbefore: '^ini.foo=bar'

- blockinfile:
   path: /my/file
   marker: "{mark} block2"
   block: |
    block2
    block2
    block2
   insertbefore: '^ini.bar=foo'
```